# Solve the initial-value problem

Tags: calculus

I need some help

Solve the initial-value problem:

dy/dx=1−sin(5x)/cos(5x)+5x+6

where (x > −1), and the conditions y= 3 when x = 0.

This is what i've got :

The integrad is 1-sin(5x)/cos(5x)+5+6 The derivative of the denominator f(x)cos(5x)+5x+6 is f'(x)-5sin(5x)+5 bringing the factor 1/5 outside the integrand. 1/5[int]sin(5x)/cos(5x)+6=−1/5 ln((cos(5x)+6))+C. Using the initial condition y=3 when x=0, we have 3=−1/5ln((cos(0)+6))+C ;1/5ln(cos(5x)+5x+6)+c Hence c=3.39, and the solution to the inital value problem is y=ln((cos(5x)+6))+3.9

Answer (score 3):

By the hypothesis we have

$$y=\int_0^x\left(\frac{1-\sin(5t)}{\cos(5t)+5t+6} \right)dt+3=\frac15\ln\left(|\cos(5x)+5x+6|\right)-\frac15\ln7+3$$

Comment: Wow, you've had a lot of posts in the last 24 hours! ;-)